# Andoid Developer Basic Training

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm doing basic android developer tutorial and Im working on dogglers app: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-project-dogglers-app?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-project-dogglers-app#3

All the test went ok, however I found one problem. In Grid option I Item Card has the vertical/horizontal layout instead od GridLayout. What am I doing wrong? I've foun out that viewType is alway 0 instead od 1, 2 or 3 that are values for respectively Horizontal, Vertical, Grid.

My Adapter:

```
class DogCardAdapter(
    private val context: Context?,
    private var layout: Int,
    private val dataset: List<Dog> = dogs
): RecyclerView.Adapter<DogCardAdapter.DogCardViewHolder>() {


    // Done: Initialize the data using the List found in data/DataSource (POWYŻEJ ZAINICJALIZOWALEM)

    /**
     * Initialize view elements
     */
    class DogCardViewHolder(view: View?, ViewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view!!) {
        // DONE: Declare and initialize all of the list item UI components
        val tvDogPhoto: ImageView = view!!.findViewById(com.example.dogglers.R.id.dog_photo)
        val tvDogName: TextView = view!!.findViewById(com.example.dogglers.R.id.dog_name)
        val tvDogAge: TextView = view!!.findViewById(com.example.dogglers.R.id.dog_age)
        val tvDogHobbies: TextView = view!!.findViewById(com.example.dogglers.R.id.dog_hobbies)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DogCardViewHolder {
        // DONE: Use a conditional to determine the layout type and set it accordingly.
        //  if the layout variable is Layout.GRID the grid list item should be used. Otherwise the
        //  the vertical/horizontal list item should be used.
        // DONE Inflate the layout
        /** val layoutType = if (viewType==Layout.GRID) {
            R.layout.grid_list_item
        }else{
            R.layout.vertical_horizontal_list_item
        }
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutType,parent,false)
        */
        //layout = 3
        val text = viewType.toString()
        val duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

        val toast = Toast.makeText(parent.context, text, duration)
        toast.show()


         val adapterLayout = if (viewType==3) {
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(com.example.dogglers.R.layout.grid_list_item,parent,false)
        }else{
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(com.example.dogglers.R.layout.vertical_horizontal_list_item,parent,false)
        }
        // DONE: Null should not be passed into the view holder. This should be updated to reflect
        //  the inflated layout.
        return DogCardViewHolder(adapterLayout,layout)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataset.size // DONE: return the size of the data set instead of 0

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DogCardAdapter.DogCardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // DONE: Get the data at the current position
        val dog = dataset[position]
        // DONE: Set the image resource for the current dog
        holder.tvDogPhoto.setImageResource(dog.imageResourceId)
        // DONE: Set the text for the current dog's name
        holder.tvDogName.text = dog.name
        // DONE: Set the text for the current dog's age
        val resources = context?.resources
        holder.tvDogAge.text = resources?.getString(com.example.dogglers.R.string.dog_age, dog.age)
        // Done: Set the text for the current dog's hobbies by passing the hobbies to the
        //  R.string.dog_hobbies string constant.
        //  Passing an argument to the string resource looks like:
        //  resources?.getString(R.string.dog_hobbies, dog.hobbies)
        holder.tvDogHobbies.text = resources?.getString(com.example.dogglers.R.string.dog_hobbies, dog.hobbies)
    }

}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I updated your question to include the source code of your adapter instead of a Github link. A full project of code is too much to share for a question on StackOverflow, and also code must be included in your question so it is sure to remain for future readers here.

Answer (score 1):

The `layout` property that is defined inside your Adapter's constructor is what is supposed to determine which layout to inflate. You used `viewType`, which is a value that is used by Adapters when there are *different* types of views in the *same* adapter, such as if one list item type is a subsection header.

So, replace

```
val adapterLayout = if (viewType==3) //...
```

with

```
val adapterLayout = if (layout == 3) //...
```

The source code in this CodeLab unfortunately also promotes a couple of bad practices. I don't know if they put those in to see if you'll spot and fix them, or if it's just sloppy design.

1. This adapter is attached to a RecyclerView with a Context. It doesn't make sense for it to have a nullable Context property because it will never exist in the absence of a Context and is useless without one, so there's no reason to make it nullable and then have all those nullsafe `?.` calls in `onBindViewHolder`.
2. DogCardViewHolder's constructor takes a nullable `view` parameter and immediately asserts that it is non-null in the super-constructor call. This is nonsensical. It pushes what should be a compile error to a runtime crash for no reason, and results in a bunch of pointless `!!` calls inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your DogCardViewHolder has two parameters.
In the original source code as of 20 JUN 2022, the code is as ff:

```
class DogCardViewHolder(view: View?): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view!!) {
     ...
}
```

So in your onCreateViewHolder class the return DogCardViewHolder() should contain the appropriate layout based on the layout var as mentioned by @Tenfour04 .

I would write the code as below:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DogCardViewHolder {
    val layoutType = when(layout) {
        Layout.GRID -> {
            R.layout.grid_list_item
        }
        else -> {
            R.layout.vertical_horizontal_list_item
        }
    }

    val adaptTo = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutType, parent, false)
    return DogCardViewHolder(adaptTo)
}
```

Small touch (not functionally relevant):
Notice I used the constant written into the source code at
java/com/example/dogglers/const/Layout.kt

Directly coding 3 into the if/when condition could be confusing.