# Android DiffUtil Doesn't Notify Properly

Tags: android, kotlin

I was following along the [Android Room With a View](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin) tutorial.

The tutorial makes use of DiffUtil to compute changes in the list and update the RecyclerView accordingly.

However, when removing or adding items to the RecyclerView, DiffUtil always causes the entire RecyclerView to reload, instead of calling the correct `notifyItemRemoved` or `notifyItemInserted`.

My Adapter:

```kotlin
class MarksAdapter(private val context: Context) :
    ListAdapter<Mark, MarksAdapter.MarkViewHolder>(MarksComparator()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MarkViewHolder {
        return MarkViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MarkViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val mark = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(context, mark)
    }

    class MarkViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private var mark: Mark? = null

        fun bind(context: Context, mark: Mark) {
            this.mark = mark
            // Removed for brevity...
        }

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): MarkViewHolder {
                val view: View =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false)
                return MarkViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    class MarksComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Mark>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Mark, newItem: Mark): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Mark, newItem: Mark): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }
}
```

From the activity/fragment:

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.recyclerViewMarks.apply {
            marksAdapter = MarksAdapter(context)
            adapter = marksAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MarksOverviewFragment.requireContext())
        }

        marksViewModel.allMarks.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { marks ->
            marks?.let { marksAdapter.submitList(it) }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it some more, the only place where I can actually influence what DiffUtil does, is within the `DiffUtil.Callback`.

So after changing:

```kotlin
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return newList[newItemPosition] === oldList[oldItemPosition]
}
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return newList[newItemPosition] == oldList[oldItemPosition]
}
```

to:

```kotlin
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return newList[newItemPosition].Uid == oldList[oldItemPosition].Uid
}
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return newList[newItemPosition] == oldList[oldItemPosition]
}
```

(notice the comparison of `Uid` instead of identity)

...the DiffUtil works as expected.

What I'm not sure however, is why it worked in the tutorial, but not for me.

Comment: Because of object equality. Either `mark` inst a data class or it doesn't have constructor params. Objects are compared on `equals()/hashCode()`: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html

Comment: @JakeB Yeah I've realized that the tutorial worked because they never left the activity of the recyclerview, so the objects where never re-created, therefore identity comparison (===) worked. In my app you navigate to a different activity, delete an item, navigate back, so the objects aren't the same anymore.

Comment: Android CodeLabs are full of so many little sloppy errors like that...always have to be on your toes if you're new to Android and following those. I found some other pretty bad ones in this other Code Lab...https://stackoverflow.com/a/70175588/506796